# I am getting a Stripe signature error: #<Stripe::SignatureVerificationError: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am currently working on my webhooks and I have an error in my Webhooks controller.

This is the error:

```
#<Stripe::SignatureVerificationError: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload>
No template found for WebhooksController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 1ms (Allocations: 594)
```

After a log time trying to debug this problem I found out it comes from these lines as the last code I can see in my console is the error and "Signature error"...

```
rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError => e
      # Invalid signature
      puts "Signature error"
      p e
      return
    end
```

Here is the controller:

```
class WebhooksController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    payload = request.body.read
    sig_header = request.env['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = nil

    begin
      event = Stripe::Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][:webhook]
      )
    rescue JSON::ParserError => e
      status 400
      # Invalid payload
      puts "Payload error"
      return
    rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError => e
      # Invalid signature
      puts "Signature error"
      p e
      return
    end


    # Handle the event
    case event.type
    when 'checkout.session.completed'
      booking = Booking.find_by(checkout_session_id: event.data.object.id)
      booking.update(paid: true)
      booking.save

      # @booking = Booking.where(checkout_session_id: event.data.object.id)
      # @booking.update(paid: true)
      # @booking.save
    end

    render json: { message: 'success' }
  end
end
```

Any help would be awesome as I've been struggling with this for a while now.

Comment: My wild guess is that you might need to parse the response body to get the actual JSON payload instead of using it as is in `construct_event`...

Answer (score 5):

Verifying webhook signatures usually fails for 2 specific reasons:

1. Using the wrong webhook secret
2. Passing a different payload than what Stripe really sent you

The first one is fairly easy to debug but it trips up a lot of developers. When you create a WebhookEndpoint (in the API or the Dashboard) you get a `secret` back that looks like `whsec_12334ABC...`. You need to make sure that your code uses that exact secret to be able to verify the signature. Note that if you use the Stripe CLI to test this flow, it gives you a *different secret* and you have to use that specific one in that case.

If you're confident you are using the right secret, then the second common root cause is the payload's content. When Stripe generates the signature, it does it on a specific version of the payload as JSON. For you to verify the signature, you have to use the exact same payload back.

The problem is that a lot of web frameworks like Express for Node.js or Rails for Ruby will tamper with the raw payload. When it receives the request, it sees JSON and so it tries to be helpful and parses the data for you. Then when you ask for the content, instead of giving you the original content/payload it just re-serializes the JSON to a string. Doing that often changes the raw payload such as removing/adding spaces/indentation or changing the order of the properties themselves. If the payload is not identical to what Stripe sent you, the signature can't match and so it errors.

With Rails, you might want to try `request.raw_post` or find a similar solution to get to the exact raw JSON sent to you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I really appreciate it. How would I implement the `request.raw:post` ? As in where do I put it in the code because I tried a couple of lines and it gives me an undefined method error

Comment: That was just an example I found in another SO answer which seems to be https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-raw_post but it might depends on your overall integration

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I have this same issue with a Laravel app, invalid signature. I have quadruple-checked the secret key, but in my case my app works fine on my local dev but fails on production server (giving 'invalid signature' and returning 500 to Stripe). Since both dev and prod use the same code, can I rule out the parsing JSON issue? If so, what options do I have diagnosing further?