# Stripe Webhook Invalid Signature in Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

`Stripe::Webhook.construct_event` is raising `Stripe::SignatureVerificationError` when running request specs with rspec.

Using `byebug` `Stripe::Webhook::Signature.verify_header` is returning true. After continuing, the exception `Stripe::SignatureVerificationError` is raised.

From reviewing the source, it seems that the first call in `Stripe::Webhook.construct_event` is `Stripe::Webhook::Signature.verify_header`.

Why would the call in the debug console return true but apparently return false when it is called in `.construct_event`?

#### Webhook Controller

```rb
class WebHooks::StripeController < WebHooksController

  # Entry point for Stripe webhooks. This method
  # will verify the signature and dispatch to the
  # appropriate method. It will log warning if
  # the webhook type is unknown. The method dispatched is the
  # webhook type with underscores instead of dots.
  def create
    payload = request.body.read
    sig_header = request.headers['Stripe-Signature']
    event = nil
    byebug
    # Byebug Console
    Stripe::Webhook::Signature.verify_header(payload, sig_header, Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:signing_secret]) 
    # => True, this returns true

    begin
      event = Stripe::Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:signing_secret]
      )
    rescue JSON::ParserError => e
      # Invalid payload
      head :unprocessable_entity
      return
    rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError => e
      # Invalid signature
      Rails.logger.error("⚠️  Stripe signature verification failed.")
      head :unauthorized
      return
    end

    type = event.type.gsub('.', '_')

    begin
      public_send(type)
    rescue NoMethodError
      Rails.logger.warn("Unknown webhook type: #{params[:type]}")
      head :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

end
```

#### Spec

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "WebHooks::Stripe::Signature", type: :request do

  context "with a valid signature" do
    it "returns 200" do
      event = { type: "not_implemented" }
      headers = {
        "Stripe-Signature" => stripe_event_signature(event.to_json)
      }
      post "/web_hooks/stripe", params: event.to_json, headers: headers
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200) # This fails
    end
  end

  context "an invalid signature" do
    it "returns 401" do
      post "/web_hooks/stripe", params: { type: "not_implemented" }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
    end
  end

end
```

#### Stripe Helper

```rb
module StripeTestHelper
  def stripe_event_signature(payload)
    time = Time.now
    secret = Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:signing_secret]
    signature = Stripe::Webhook::Signature.compute_signature(time, payload, secret)
    Stripe::Webhook::Signature.generate_header(
      time,
      signature,
      scheme: Stripe::Webhook::Signature::EXPECTED_SCHEME
    )
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple reasons as to why you might be getting this, `Stripe::SignatureVerificationError` error. The first being that a wrong value for your webhook signing secret, which would look something like `whsec_`, was used. You can retrieve the correct one from your [Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/webhooks) by clicking on ‘Reveal’.

If you've confirmed that you've used the right secret, then the issue might be on the payload's content which likely is the issue here. This answer on another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790959/i-am-getting-a-stripe-signature-error-stripesignatureverificationerror-no) talks about this in depth. The summary is that Rails for Ruby will tamper with the raw payload and if it's not identical to what Stripe sent you, the signature won't be a match.

As for next steps, you'd want try `request.raw_post` or find a similar solution to get to the exact raw JSON sent to you.